# mute command in discord.js. This is my code so far, but it doesnt work yet

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This command should be able to mute users, but I dont know what s wrong with it. I think there is someting wrong in the var's but i dont  know.

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'r/';
const TOKEN = 'token'; 

client.on('message', msg => {
    msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'mute') ;{
        var muteRole = msg.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase().includes('muted'));
        var muteChannel = msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name.includes('modlogs'));
        var muteUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
        var muteReason = msg.content.slice(prefix.length + 30);

        if(!msg.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.channel.send('Du brauchst die Berechtigung um Mitglieder zu muten');
        if(!muteUser) return msg.channel.send('Du musst einen gültigen Benutzer angeben');
        if(!muteChannel) return msg.channel.send('Der Server muss über einen #modlogs Kanal verfügen');
        if(!muteRole) return msg.channel.send('Der Server muss über eine <muted> Rolle verfügen');
        if(!msg.guild.member(client.user.id).hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return msg.channel.send('Ich habe keine Berechtigungen');
        if(!muteReason) muteReason='Bitte gebe einen Grund zum Muten dieses Mitgliedes an';

        var muteEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Mute')
        .addField('Gemutete Benutzer', muteUser)
        .addField('Begründung', muteReason)
        .setFooter(`Gemutet von **${msg.author.tag}**`)
        .setTimestamp();

        muteUser.addRole(muteRole);
        msg.channel.send(`**${muteUser}** ist gemutet`);
        muteChannel.send(muteEmbed);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost right, though you are calling `muteUser.addRole`, which is not a valid function on Discord.js v12. What you'll want to do is change that line to the following:

```
muteUser.roles.add(muteRole);
```

This way you are actually calling the "Add Roles" function, and the user will be given that specific role.

An extra thing I did notice within your command is that you are looking for any role which contains the word `muted`, and any channel within your guild which contains the name `modlogs`. I wouldn't suggest you to do that, as having 2 or more roles/channels containing those words will cause the bot to return 2 or more responses to the trigger.

If you'd like to fix that, use the following:

```
const muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Muted');
```

This will find specifically for a role with the name of "Muted", or you can use "muted" if you have it lower case.

```
const punishments_channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name ==="modlogs")
```

This will let the bot search for 1 single channel which name is exactly `modlogs`.

I hope this helped, and best of luck with your project!